# Where will the function intersect its inverse

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, inverse-function

I am stuck on the following question. This came in my exam today.
It gave the following graph :

[image]

The question asked what would be a reasonable point where the graph would intersect with its inverse. Is it $(2,3), (-2,3),(3,3),(3,-3),(3,-4)$?

I only knew that in order to take inverse of a function, we nee to consider the reflection of the curve about the line $y=x$.
But I had no idea how to take the reflection of this given curve.

Also I could answer this question. I want to learn how to do these type of questions.
Can someone kindly help me to solve this?

Comment: You just said how to reflect the curve. If you can't do it "mentally", flip the paper alongside the diagonal (maybe draw the diagonal to help you) so that you can see through and in another paper draw the curve reflected and you get you inverse. Anyway, notice that the points where $f(x)=x$ is the same when you flip it, so where the graph of $f$ meets the diagonal, also $f^{-1}$ meets the diagonal in that point

Comment: HINT. Point $(2,3)$ in the graph of the function becomes point $(3,2)$ in the graph of its inverse. Hence...

Comment: @Alessandro; Its still not clear to me

Answer (score 1):

*Claim:* For each **strictly increasing** function $f$ and each $x$ in its domain, $$f(x)=f^{-1}(x)\iff f(x)=x.$$

*Proof*

1. RHS $\implies \big(x=f^{-1}(x)\,$ and $\,f(x)=x\big)\implies$ LHS.
2. For the foward direction, let's assume for the sake of contradiction that $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ and $f(x)\ne x$ are both true for some strictly increasing $f$ and some $x$ in its domain. The former implies that $f(f(x))=x,$ while the latter implies that $f(x)<x\,$ or $\,f(x)>x,$ which, since $f$ is increasing, respectively implies that $f(f(x))<f(x)\,$ or $\,f(f(x))>f(x),$ which, by the previous inequality pair, respectively implies that $f(f(x))<x\,$ or $\,f(f(x))>x,$ that is, that $f(f(x))\ne x.$ We have derived a contradiction, so the forward direction must be true.

P.S. Note that in general, $$f(x)=f^{-1}(x) \kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies f(x)=\pm x.$$ [For example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b65u9to2wr), let $g(x)=-\dfrac1x\,$ and $\,h(x)=1-x.$ 
Then $y=g(x)$ and $y=g^{-1}(x)$ have infinitely many intersections, as do $y=h(x)$ and $y=h^{-1}(x);$ yet $y=\pm x$ has finitely many intersections with $y=g(x)$ and $y=h(x).$

---

From the above-proven theorem, since the given function is increasing and intersects the line $y=x$ exactly once, it must intersect with its inverse exactly once at some $(x,x).$ So, from the given options, $(3,3)$ is a reasonable point where the graph intersects with its inverse.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ then $f(f^{-1})(x) = f(f(x)) = x $.

It seems that there is a value $a$ such that $f(a) =a $ and such that if $x>a$ we have $f(x)>x$ and such that if $x<a$ we have $f(x)<x$. Because the line $y=x$ intersects the curve only once.

It follows that if $x<a$ we have $f(f(x)) < x$ and if $x>a$ we have $f(f(x)) > x$.

Hence the only feasible point is $(a,a)$ which looking at the options could only be $(3,3)$.

Comment: Note that what we used is that the line $y=x$ interesects our curve exactly once.