# If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists but $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ does not, why can $\lim_{x \to a}[f(x) +g(x)]$ not exist?

Tags: limits

From James Stewart 7th edition. The answer provided is that this can never exist.

I have looked at the limit laws and all their criteria but cannot come up with why this can never happen.

Why is this the case?

The following is the answer but I cannot follow their reasoning beyond the algebraic shuffling.
[image]

Comment: Which part of the proof do you fail to understand?

Comment: The very last line saying there is a contradiction.

Comment: The previous sentence contains a proof of the fact that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exists, since it is equal to $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)+g(x)]-\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$. But it was being assumed that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you know what a "contradiction" means? At the beginning, $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ is assumed to exist. But you end up with the conclusion that it exists, that's the contradiction.

Comment: @user1046533 "at the beginning,..assumed to not exist" you mean

Comment: @AmanKushwaha: ah, yes; that's a typo. Thanks.

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos  so because we assume limx→a[f(x)+g(x)] exists and we assume limx→af(x) exists then their difference must exist according the difference limit law, but we are also assuming that limx→ag(x) doesn't exist... so this equality we've made can never exist?

Comment: Yes. That's called [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).

Comment: How was I ever supposed to figure this out? This is just an introductory book on calculus? What was I not taught that would allow me to get questions like this right?

Comment: "How was I ever supposed to figure this out? "... By learning I suppose...

Comment: @user312484 Re: the 4th comment abovev this: that's a good summary, and, to be super clear: the contradiction comes from having derived that lim(f+g) both exists and doesn't exist, in other words, from having derived a pair of conflicting statements, which is logically impossible.

Comment: @user312484 And yes, it's normal for this proof technique to seem a little magical, especially when you're new to it. For example, in my [most recent such proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4440456/21813), even though I thought that a contradiction proof was best, I didn't start off knowing the exact contradiction that I would derive; it only emerged as I was developing the proof.

Comment: @ryang thank you for the sympathy, being sideswiped by information that I didn't know to answer a question is very demoralizing.  I guess I will have to read up and be prepared.

Comment: @user1046533 no where in the book is this technique taught or alluded to in any of the regular chapter problems.

Comment: @user312484 The book probably expects that you've encountered the technique (which you can think of as a sort of 'logical' common sense) in a prior course/book.